# Does event, onBlur, work with the React Admin useInput hook on custom field?

Tags: react-admin

I have a custom field that takes JSON and dynamically prints out TextField objects.
For each TextField I have an onChange and onBlur event. The onChange is for updating the state and the onBlur is for updating the final value to be past to the API and saved.
I'm using the useInput hook to save the updated value, however, when I use onBlur it doesn't save the value.
If I only use onChange it DOES save the value, but only the first key stroke, which is why I switched to onBlur. Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
const DefaultField = props => {
    const {
        input,
    } = useInput(props.record);

    let parsedObj = JSON.parse(props.record.values);

    const [defaultState, setDefaultState] = React.useState({
        websiteLink: parsedObj.websiteLink,
        menuInstructionsLink: parsedObj.menuInstructionsLink,
        surveyLink: parsedObj.surveyLink
    });

    const handleBlur = (event) => {
        parsedObj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        props.record.values= JSON.stringify(values);
        //event.target.value is the expected value but it's not persisted when I save it.
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setDefaultState({ ...defaultState, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    };

    return (
        <FormControl component="fieldset">
            <FormGroup {...input} id="defaultGroup" aria-label="position">
                <React.Fragment>
                    { Object.keys(parsedObj).map((key) => (
                        <TextField
                            id="standard-full-width"
                            name={key}
                            label={key}
                            onBlur={handleBlur}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            style={{ margin: 8, width: '500px' }}
                            value={defaultState[key]}
                            fullWidth
                            margin="normal"
                        />
                    ))}
                </React.Fragment>
            </FormGroup>
        </FormControl>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I never solved it properly, but I did discover that the dataProvider was being called twice. The first time it would send the expected values, but the second time the values were set back to the original, however I noticed that the field "previousData" had the values I needed. For now I'm just making sure to use the "previousData" field. This isn't the prettiest solution, but for now it's working. Maybe it's a bug or something sinister is going on.